# uWSGI and .pyo files

Tags: python, python-2.7, bytecode, uwsgi, python-2.x

I am trying to run a web app off nothing but .pyo files. The idea is to deploy without the .py files altogether.

My problem is that I cannot find a war of running uWSGI in "python -O" mode, so I always get import errors as soon as the imported file is only available as a .pyo file. The exact error looks like the error I would see if I ran the importing file in Python without the *-O* flag.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/some/path/wsgi.py", line 20, in <module>
    from foobar import app
ImportError: No module named foobar
```

If I make the entry point a .pyo file as well, I even get

```
File "/some/path/wsgi.pyo", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xf3' in file /some/path/wsgi.pyo on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
failed to parse file /some/path/wsgi.pyo
```

It is obvious from the second error message, that uWSGI clearly does not expect byte-code.

I know that there is an [*optimize* setting](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#optimize) for the uWSGI. However, it seems to be undocumented and doesn't fix my problem. I suspect that it means that uWSGI optimises the Python code it is fed but not that it becomes able to read optimised byte-code.

Is there a way of configuring uWSGI so that it can execute optimised Python byte-code?

I suspect that it doesn't matter but I'm using the Python2 uWGSI plug-in.